# How to trigger validation on one property when another property has been validated, using custom ValidationAttribute and INotifyDataErrorInfo

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, validationattribute, inotifydataerrorinfo

Up until recently, I have used a custom extended version of the `IDataErrorInfo` interface. My extension enables me to work with multiple errors simultaneously and so far, it's served me very well. However, with the introduction of the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface, I thought I'd experiment with it to see if there was any improvement.

After following some online tutorials, I got it working with the various `ValidationAttribute`s from the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace`. Using these `Attribute`s let you provide basic validation rules like this:

```
[MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "Name must be longer than 3 characters.")]
public string Name
{
    get { return name; }
    set { name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Name"); Validate("Name", name); }
}
```

Initially, it seemed pretty good, as the error messages plug right into the `Valaidation.Errors` collection available in the applied `ErrorTemplate`s. However, most of the built in validation rules are really basic and I'm used to having to implement complicated validation rules that involve other property values.

So I set out to find a way to create a simple validation rule that involved multiple properties: A rule that one of two or more fields must be set. So I declared a class that extended the `ValidationAttribute` and after searching online, found a way to access the other property values.

I knocked up a basic UI with a custom `ErrorTemplate` applied to each `TextBox`, that displayed the `Validation.Errors` collection for the data bound property:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ErrorTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Border BorderBrush="#4FFF0000" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0,10">
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
        </Border>
        <Image Name="WarningImage" Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication1;component/Images/Warning_16.png" Margin="5,0,0,0" Tag="{Binding}" />
        <Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=WarningImage}" Placement="Right" Margin="5,0,0,0" AllowsTransparency="True" IsOpen="True">
            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#4FFF0000" CornerRadius="5" Background="White" Padding="5" Margin="10">
                <Border.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect Color="Red" Opacity="0.5" BlurRadius="15" ShadowDepth="0" />
                </Border.Effect>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorContent}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

With my custom `Attribute` set on the `Name` property, I managed to add a `ValidationResult` into the `Validation.Errors` collection through the interface when neither property was set, but here's the problem: If I added a value into one of the other `TextBox`es data bound to the other required properties, the error message in the first `TextBox` would stay there.

If I went back to the first `TextBox` and typed something, then the validation would work, so even if I deleted the value, it still knew that one of the required properties was set. So the validation code works, but the problem is that property changes to the other required properties do not trigger the validation in the `Name` property.

Even when I applied the same custom `Attribute` to the other required properties, the same thing happened... each validation error would only clear when typing in its related `TextBox`. I also tried the built in `CustomValidationAttribute` which enables us to call a method in the class to validate with, but the end result was the same.

The validation code works, but is just not triggered from the other required property changes. I even tried calling the `Validate` method, passing in the names of the other properties, but that ended in a continuous loop. So the question is, how can I trigger a validation on one property when another property has been validated?

Comment: is it possible for you to post a working sample for the same? I am interested to see that.

Comment: Wow... is this question not long enough already? I just sourced everything from online... what did you want to see? Perhaps I can provide some links for you?

Comment: Question has sufficient details to understand the same, all I am looking is a working sample code so that I don't have to re-write the whole code to simulate the same and I can directly focus on the blocking issue.

Comment: Oh right... unfortunately, there's just a ridiculous amount of code involved - that's why I didn't include it to start with. I'll see if I can knock up a more simple example when I get home tonight.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did, in a class containing `From` and `To` properties. I wanted to validate that `From` is less than or equal to `To`.

The validation logic is applied using `CustomValidationAttribute`, which is easier than creating your own validation attribute classes. You simply tell it the type of your class, and the name of the method to call that contains your validation logic (the method must have a specific signature though). Here is my relevant code:-

```
    [CustomValidation(typeof(MyModel), "ValidateRange")]
    public double From
    {
        get
        {
            return _from;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_from != value)
            {
                _from = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("From");

                // Validate the other side
                ValidateProperty("To", _to);
            }
        }
    }

    [CustomValidation(typeof(MyModel), "ValidateRange")]
    public double To
    {
        get
        {
            return _to;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_to != value)
            {
                _to = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("To");

                // Validate the other side
                ValidateProperty("From", _from);
            }
        }
    }

    private static ValidationResult ValidateRange(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var model = validationContext.ObjectInstance as MyModel;

        if (model.From > model.To)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Invalid range");
        }

        return null;
    }
```

As you can see, the code in one property setter forces validation of the "other" property, exactly as you mentioned in your last paragraph. There's no reason why it should go into an endless loop, unless your validation code is trying to set one of the properties, which would trigger another call to Validate(), and so on, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your response... this looks promising. I'll try it out when I get home tonight.

Comment: After trying your suggestion, it appears that it doesn't work at all. It shows the validation errors for each property on the other property's `TextBox`'s `ErrorTemplate`s. It just the same problem but in reverse.

Comment: @Sheridan apologies - I forgot to mention that my model's base class calls ValidateProperty() from within the OnPropertyChanged() event (with hindsight perhaps not such a good design, as it's not clear this is happening). So in the above code, the "From" property getter will first validate the "From" property (internally via OnPropertyChanged), then validate the "To" property via the explicit call to ValidateProperty().